# Problem in using hash tables as the solution to this problem

Tags: c++, hashtable, std

Andryusha is an orderly boy and likes to keep things in their place.

Today he faced a problem to put his socks in the wardrobe. He has n distinct pairs of socks which are initially in a bag. The pairs are numbered from 1 to n. Andryusha wants to put paired socks together and put them in the wardrobe. He takes the socks one by one from the bag, and for each sock he looks whether the pair of this sock has been already took out of the bag, or not. If not (that means the pair of this sock is still in the bag), he puts the current socks on the table in front of him. Otherwise, he puts both socks from the pair to the wardrobe.

Andryusha remembers the order in which he took the socks from the bag. Can you tell him what is the maximum number of socks that were on the table at the same time? This is the problem.

https://codeforces.com/contest/782/problem/A This is the problem statement.

```
int main()
{
    init_code();
    int n ; 
    cin >> n ; 
    unordered_map <int ,int> hash;
    int count  = 0 ;
    int max = count ;
    int s;
    while(n--)
    {   cin >> s; 
        hash[s]++;
        if(hash[s] == 1)
            count++;
        if(hash[s] == 2)
            count--;  
        if(max <= count)
            max = count; 
    }

    cout << max ; 
    return 0; 
}
```

https://codeforces.com/contest/782/submission/119472076

This is my answer to the problem using hash tables, i.e using unordered_map in C++ STL.

The preferred approach would be to use an array.

Can someone help me out, I feel like my logic is correct,I am not able get the right answer for test case 4, which is very large number. I am using hash tables.

The problem is to find the the maximum number of socks that were on the table at the same time. Where you can take one sock at a time.

Can someone tell me why hash tables are a bad approach to this problem or is not giving me the right answer.

Comment: A [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) should be probided in your question directly as text ,not as an external link.

Comment: https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/782/A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are `2*n` numbers to read and process, but you processed only `n` numbers. Process `2*n` numbers to fix.